# Where do I publish an article about DnD?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, publishing

I am currently writing an essay/article about TTRPGs (primarily Dungeons and Dragons) and theatre for my university, but I'm thinking about publishing it for others to see if they're interested and to let it go a little further than just my professor's desk. However, I don't really know where I would publish something like that or how to go about doing so.

Does anyone have any ideas about where to submit an article like this? or have any experience with writing/publishing research/academia about TTRPGs?

Comment: Im not entirely sure what you're looking for. TRPG forums? Sites like Reddit? Perhaps looking into getting specific TRPG news sites to hire you / commission you? Either way, I'm not sure the question would fit this site's format. Maybe with some more criteria on what you're looking for, so we can guide tou towards that goal. Either way, welcome to the site! Thanks for taking the tour, happy stacking!

Comment: Welcome To RPGE.SE! Take the [tour] or visit the [help] to have some guidance about posting questions and answers! What's the topic of your article? By what you are writing in your question, it seems that you are interested in academy publishing.

Comment: @DaleM I poked people over there to ask if it'd be on-topic. Waiting on a response....

Comment: First thought: "I know this [great magazine](https://dmmagazine.blogspot.com/2021/05/interactive-fantasy-only-scholastic.html) for scholarly articles about gaming..."  After looking for link: "Oh, it last published in 1995..."  Sigh.  Get off my lawn.

Comment: @DaleM I lurk on Academia (maybe I'll post there, now that I got my degree) but they don't really do "Which journal should I submit to?" that I've seen.

I'm aware this could be construed as opinion/shopping, but I think this group actually has the expertise to make an expert suggestion if we want to.